# Get a 3rd point xyz from two known points ( observers) only having azimouths and angle of degradation.

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let's say that two observers on known coordinates and known distance between them, different elevation level between them. Both of them observe the same point on the fields laying in front of them and get the azimuth and degradation level from their position to the observed point. How could they calculate the xyz coordinates of that point? I know that I can use the law of cosines on flat land but that xyz confuses me a lot.

Comment: Please consider adding a diagram

Comment: I can't. I tried to but I am still a newbie and the system does not allow me to.

Comment: If you can put a link to the diagram in your question, someone will post the diagram for you.

Comment: Let me elaborate more while I am not allowed to upload a diagram, so I can make this more understandable. Person A and person B creates the base of the triangles. Their coordinates are known so the length of the base is known. Now Person one creates two angles to point C ( the observable object), one angle is the azimuth and the second is degradation angle, while he is on a hill and the object is on a field lower to him. Same thing applies to the other person, only he is on a different hight level from Personson 1 and the observed object. That creates us 2 triangles with the same base.

Comment: Triangle ABC with AB as the base and Angles CAB and ABC the azimouths from Person A and Person B to C point ( the observed object). Triangle ABC1 has the same base with ABC and Angles C1AB and ABC1 are the degradation angles from the observers hight to the observed object. How can I solve those cosines law ASA triangles with xyz points and Angles?